# Rendering Tilemap on the screen correctly

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm having a strange problem rendering my level based on tilemap correctly.
On the y axis all the tiles are normal and aligned, instead on the x axis they seem to be divided by a space i can't figure out why...

I created a matrix with enum values(from 0 to 2) and i cycled my matrix in a for
loop to render the tile with the current number:
ex. GROUND = 0; etc...

Here is a photo of what it looks like
http://it.tinypic.com/r/ali261/8

Here is the sprite for the tile
http://it.tinypic.com/r/21kggw5/8

i will add the code down here.

```
for(int y = 0; y < 15; y++)
            {
                for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
                {
                    if(map[y][x] == GROUND)
                        render(tileTex,x*64 - camera.x,y*64 - camera.y,&gTileSprite[0],0,NULL,SDL_FLIP_NONE);
                    else if(map[y][x] == UGROUND)
                        render(tileTex,x*64 - camera.x,y*64 - camera.y,&gTileSprite[1],0,NULL,SDL_FLIP_NONE);
                    else if(map[y][x] == SKY)
                        render(tileTex,x*64 - camera.x,y*64 - camera.y,&gTileSprite[2],0,NULL,SDL_FLIP_NONE);

                    tBox[y][x].x = x*64;
                    tBox[y][x].y = y*64;
                    tBox[y][x].w = TILE_WIDTH;
                    tBox[y][x].h = TILE_HEIGHT;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried to compare a 64x64 tile from the sprite-map with a single 64x64 tile rendered to the screen? It's hard to tell without seeing the sprite-sheet, but it looks like there's some filtering (smoothing) happening on the tiles. If the tiles are surrounded by transparent areas, the edge pixels may become blurred (blended) with the transparent pixels. Seeing the sprite-sheet would definitely be an advantage in diagnosing this problem. The code above displays no obvious problems to me.

Comment: i added it now @enhzflep

Comment: you are a genious my friend @enhzflep thanks to you i found the problem that actually was on the tilemap. I zoomed the image and i found this damn blurred pixels! please make an answer so i can accept your answer.
Steve

Comment: either that, or I've made the same mistake in the past and can work from memory. Hint: It's not the first. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to the comments above, one must be careful to avoid any blurring along the edges of tiles, since their repetition will make any defects more obvious than if they were viewed in isolation.

Blurring may be introduced in the process of drawing portions of the tilemap to the final/intermediate target, or as seems (and has been confirmed) in this case, the source material may have blurred edges.

Particularly when working with images of such 'low` pixel dimensions, one must be vigilant and ensure that any/all resizing operations are performed in an image-editor without re-sampling.

While bilinear/cubic re-sampling may be desired when blitting the assembled image to the screen, it is *never* desirable for such re-sampling to happen to the source material.